# Message passing solution

Tags: mpi, message-queue, message-passing

I am creating an application involving concurrent actors which communicate through pre-specified FIFO message queues (Essentially a [Kahn process network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahn_process_networks) ). Actors do not (MUST not) share memory.

I am relatively inexperienced in this field and in this regard I would like to know if third party message passing libraries (eg. MPI implementations - open-MPI) over significant advantages over linux message queues which I am somewhat familiar with.

I do not need to support operating systems other than linux or languages other than C/C++. The application should take advantage of a multi-processor system, however the processes will reside on a single computer system and will not be distributed over a network.

Comment: MPI provides code portability and network transparence. Obviously you don't need any of those at that moment. On the other hand, MPI provides some nice abstractions that you can make use of and your code will (almost) automatically be cluster-ready